When were Peano axioms formulated purely in first-order logic?
It is mentioned on the Wikipedia article about Peano axioms that:

The ninth, final axiom is a second-order statement of the principle of mathematical induction over the natural numbers, which makes this formulation close to second-order arithmetic. A weaker first-order system is obtained by explicitly adding the addition and multiplication operation symbols and replacing the second-order induction axiom with a first-order axiom schema. The term Peano arithmetic is sometimes used for specifically naming this restricted system.

My question is: when was Peano arithmetic first formulated in the framework of first-order logic?

Hilbert-Bernays, Grundlagen (1934).

Thoralf Skolem (1933), Über die Unmöglichkeit einer vollständigen Charakterisierung der Zahlenreihe mittels eines endlichen Axiomensystems.
